# Firebase - keep user signed in while localStorage object is valid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app I'm building with Ionic, Angular2, and Firebase.

What I'm currently doing is that when a user log's in or registers, their `auth.currentUser` information is being saved in `localStorage`. My code is currently assuming that if a user has the `user` variable in `localStorage` set that the user is also signed in. However, I just realized that that isn't actually the case.

My `localStorage` variable `user` looks like this:

[image]

and I'm getting it like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  Promise.all([ //data storage get all..
    this.storage.get('user')
  ])
  .then(([user]) => {
    this.userData = user; //set the user storage to this.userData
    console.log(this.userData)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Storage Error.");
  });
}
```

So I have all of the users information, except the fact that they aren't actually signed in... So when I do:

```
this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user)
  } else {
    console.log("Not logged in")
  }
});
```

It shows the user isn't logged in. Is it possible for me to keep the user logged in while I have the localStorage information?

Or maybe just have the login state *always* be logged in unless the user signs out? With it never expiring?

What should I do at this point? Any advice would be great! Thank you.

Comment: As Vijai said, just check for the user object from the Firebase auth. If user is not null there is someone logged in. You can still save stuff in local storage but no need to save user object as it already exist in app of someone is logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase manger user in a different way. You should not depend on localstorage to detect if user is logged it. You should depend on firebase to check if user is logged in. Since firebase is built on web sockets, it should be really quick. So let rewrite the `ngOnInit` as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;

    if (user) {
      this.userData = user;
    } else {
      // force them to reauthenticate
      user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
        .then(function() {
          // User re-authenticated.
          this.userData = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
        }).catch(function(error) {
         // An error happened.
        });
    }
}
```

Read more about managing users in Firebase here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users. Hope this helps.